# What happen if you don't use Push and Pop function in Assembly Language programming?

Tags: assembly

I tried running a very simple program without the use of push and pop and the result is the same as when the program has the function push and pop.

How does it affect the program with the push and pop in the assembly language?

Comment: You should show the source code of your very simple program. We cannot answer without it. So edit your question to improve it.

Comment: What architecture? Most likely the push/pops were there to preserve registers which are defined by the Application Binary Interface (ABI) to be non-volatile when calling a function. It might not have changed your simple program, but it could easily break other code that was expecting that code to follow the rules.

Comment: And can you call a function from another function in your program? How would you preserve the state of a function without stack?

Comment: The good news: The content of any register can be store into a table inside the data segment and this content can be reload inside and outside from a subroutine or deep nested subroutines. Preserving the state of a function with using the "mov" instruction are also simple and transparent. The Push and Pop instructions are not necessarily needed.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `push` and `pop`, fuction calls are effectively impossible to program, which means that recursion is also impossible to use. However, depending on the specific achitecture, `push` and `pop` could be simulated by other register manipulation, but typically there would be no need to do so.

Comment: You can change the `%esp` register without using `push` and `pop`

Comment: In fact, RISC architectures do not have pop and push instructions, so *"typically"* does not apply here. Also architectures can use pass by register instead of pass by stack (e.g. MIPS).

Comment: I like to use the move instruction for to save and for reload a register content inside a subroutine on Intel 80386, AMD K5, AMD K6. Because the pair of push and pop instructions execute significant slower than a pair of mov and mov instructions. The Push and Pop instructions are not necessarily needed.